# how to set textview from left if imageview disappear in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Request for traveling"
        android:textColor="#282e36"
        android:textSize="23px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="asd has requested to travel with you"
        android:textColor="#282e36"
        android:textSize="23px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Rejected"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/runnimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:src="@drawable/drive"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
        android:textColor="#8f939b"
        android:textSize="23px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is code of Notification List item Xml :

```
public class Notifcationadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Notify> values;
    Context context;
    String senderid;
    String imagepath;
    String member_id;
    String recevr_id;
    String jsonResp;

    // List<RowItem> rowItems;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LinearLayout linear2;
    DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(context);
    ArrayList<Notify> notifies;

    public Notifcationadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Notify> notifies) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.notifies = notifies;

    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
        ImageView yesimage;
        ImageView noimage;
        TextView revresetime;
        TextView rejected;
        ImageView runnimage;
        ImageView notificationuserimage;
        LinearLayout linear2;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notifcationlistitem,
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // holder.linear2 = (LinearLayout) convertView
            // .findViewById(R.id.linear2);
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.yesimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.noimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.revresetime = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.revresetime);
            holder.rejected = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rejectedrequest);
            holder.notificationuserimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.notificationuserimage);

            holder.runnimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.runnimage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // holder.txtTitle.setText("Title");
        String statustype = notifies.get(position).getNotificationType();

        if (statustype.equals("1")) {
            holder.txtTitle.setText("Request For travelling");
            holder.txtDesc.setText(notifies.get(position)
                    .getNotificationDescrpiton());

            holder.revresetime.setText(Functions
                    .setLastSeenNotifcationTime(notifies.get(position)
                            .getNotificationDatetime()));

            senderid = notifies.get(position).getNotificationSenderID();
            imagepath = "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/"

            + senderid + ".jpg";
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);

            aq.id(holder.notificationuserimage).image(imagepath);

            holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.noimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.yesimage.setTag(convertView);
            holder.yesimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View parentView = (View) arg0.getTag();
                    View view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.linear2);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.runnimage);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    new sendMesgTask().execute("Acepted");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", 10000).show();

                }
            });
            holder.noimage.setTag(convertView);
            holder.noimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View parentView = (View) v.getTag();
                    View view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view = parentView.findViewById(R.id.rejectedrequest);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "NO", 10000).show();
                    // holder.linear2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    new sendMesgTask().execute("Rjected");
                    holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.noimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.rejected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }

        else if (statustype.equals("2")) {

            holder.txtDesc.setText(notifies.get(position)
                    .getNotificationDescrpiton());
            holder.txtTitle.setText("Post");
            holder.revresetime.setText(Functions
                    .setLastSeenNotifcationTime(notifies.get(position)
                            .getNotificationDatetime()));

            holder.runnimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            senderid = notifies.get(position).getNotificationSenderID();
            imagepath = "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/"

            + senderid + ".jpg";
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
            aq.id(holder.notificationuserimage).image(imagepath);

            holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.noimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            holder.txtDesc.setText(notifies.get(position)
                    .getNotificationDescrpiton());
            holder.txtTitle.setText("Accept/ Reject ");
            holder.txtDesc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.noimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.revresetime.setText(Functions
                    .setLastSeenNotifcationTime(notifies.get(position)
                            .getNotificationDatetime()));
            senderid = notifies.get(position).getNotificationSenderID();
            imagepath = "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/" + senderid
                    + ".jpg";
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
            aq.id(holder.notificationuserimage).image(imagepath);

        }
        String notifcationsenderid = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationSenderID();
        String notisread = notifies.get(position).getNotificationStatus();
        if (notisread.equals("false")) {

            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f6f1"));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notifies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return notifies.get(position).getNotificationType();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    }
}
```

[image]

In given Screen item which has a like and dislike Button  , date is coming right of image like dislike but when ImageView is hidden date and time goes to top even you can see In Post item that date and time are appearing on the top . I need suggestions how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/motherLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Request for traveling"
        android:textColor="#282e36"
        android:textSize="23px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="asd has requested to travel with you"
        android:textColor="#282e36"
        android:textSize="23px" />

          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/motherLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Rejected"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/runnimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
        android:src="@drawable/drive"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
        android:textColor="#8f939b"
        android:textSize="23px" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code will work for you, you may need to add padding as your requriement and for alternate row colors do it in adapter class

Comment: yaar i have tried Unable to do in relative layout it was fixed so am telling u please help and usggest

Comment: ok at-least u fix  title and description text view Like given image @NavinRaj Pandey

Answer (score 0):

Too many layouts which are not needed for your situation i think, i'd suggest to try and reduce that first.
For now, replace the

```
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
```

in

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revresetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
        android:textColor="#8f939b"
        android:textSize="23px" />
```

with

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
android:layout_above="@+id/thelayoutwithtext"Post"inyourimage"
```